# C# Moving bar/image on Picturebox

Tags: c#, image, performance, graphics, picturebox

I'm creating a Windows Form application, where in Picturebox I have a static background (from image). I'm willing to add a moving bar/image at the bottom of the background (like in News from TV). The bar/image will be created dynamically (depending on received data) and it's size (width) will be far greater than this of Picturebox (only part of the bar/image will be visible at time). How can I achieve this in a manner that won't kill neither my CPU nor my RAM? Some time ago I did it with creating image of background + visible part of the bar and was refreshing the operation and box a lot, what wasn't the smartest idea due to the high usage of cpu and memory.

Thanks in advance for the help ! :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to use WPF? It's much better suited for your use case because the more powerful graphics rendering abilities.

Comment: Set the starting position, set a timer with an interval of something around 1-5ms and move `pos.X` +1 until `pos.X` equals `startPos.X + bar.Width + pictureBox.Width`, then just go `pos.X == startPos.X`. Easy isnt it!?

Comment: @C4u: Humas can only see ca 16hz and timers only run at ca 20Hz or slower so 1-5 ms is not a realistic number, 20-40ms is more likely to work.

Comment: You can either create the image and draw a portion of it in the Paint event or you could draw the data directly. Animation is usually done with a Timer that Invalidates the bottom portion of the PBox; the drawing of course happens in the Paint event. Or you could nest a Label in the PBox and move it in the Tick. In any caseyou need to allow for ca. one PBox.Width of extra and repeated data display to allow wrapping.. - When you run into trouble show us the code!

Comment: @TaW Timer at 2ms with an offset of x+1 OR Timer at 4ms with an offset of x+2 doesnt really matter for me. Even if you can only see every 2nd or 3rd move, the ones between will determine the speed of movement. Are you seriously talking about performance according whats possible for the human eye? Kidding me?

Comment: I was talking both about the effective Timer resolution (ca.25-75ms)  and, yes, of course about the human eye. Are you programming for non-humans? For smooth advances we should use floats for the positions, not queue/calculate superfluous intermediate frames..